# How to access additional method of class that implemented interface

Tags: c#

As shown in below code, I have created Sample class which implements the IPrint interface's Print method and it also has additional SampleTest method. In main section I create object of Sample class and assign it to interface. However what if I want to access SampleTest method.

Also what are the thoughts on this code? Is it ok to implement SampleTest additional method and call it from main?

---

```
interface IPrint
{
    void Print();
}

class Sample : IPrint
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Print...");
    }

    public void SampleTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SampleTest...");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPrint print = new Sample();
        print.Print();
        // How would I access SampleTest methos of Sample class here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The goal of the interface is provide a contract to work with classes that implement this interface. The benefit of this - you don't care about concrete implementation.

So, while your interface `IPrint` doesn't contain `SampleTest()` method you can't access it from object wich type is `IPrint`.

The only way, is casting your object to `Sample` class, as already been said, but I think it will be bad design, because you come back to concrete implementations.

Consider to call `SampleTest()` method from your `Print()` method if you need some additional actions to perform while print proccess. This way, your `main()` still doesn't care about which printer is used right now.

Answer (score 0):

Since object is of type sample and you assigned to IPrint so you cannot access SampleTest unless you cast your print object to Sample. This should work:

```
((Sample)print).SampleTest();
```